# What does TE and NT actually mean

Tags: pbx

I use a PBX with a Sangoma card, specifically the A500. Below is the link for the product

http://www.sangoma.com/products/a500-2-24-port-scalable-st-bri/

On the link you have a demo, which breaks down the components and explains them nicely. One things it also shows (specifically on step 3), is that the BRI module can be inserted either way, however one way is for TE and the other for NT.

I understand that TE stands for Termination equipment and that NT stands for Network Termination. But cannot seem to find any decent information that actually tells me what each of these mean and the difference between them. Could someone point me to a site or resource with this info, or explain it simply for me if you know the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISDN BRI defines different points or interfaces along the link between the telephone exchange and the end equipment in, for example, your home.

At the user equipment end, ISDN also distinguishes between different types of 'Terminal Equipment' - for example TE1 refers to specialised ISDN terminals and TE2 to 'standard' phones.

At the interface point between the line from the telephone exchange, and the local ISDN Terminal Equipment in your home, the Network Termination (NT) provides the functionality to interface between the 2 wire connection from the telephone exchange (i.e. the 2 wires that come in to your home) and the 4 wires connections to ISDN Terminal Equipment (e.g. the 4 wire connection that you plug into your ISDN phone).

Some good links to give some background:

http://homepages.uel.ac.uk/u0113650/ISDNBASIC.htm

http://docwiki.cisco.com/wiki/Integrated_Services_Digital_Network

http://www.networkmuseum.net/2011/07/isdn-bri.html

Comment: Definitely need to warp my head around this. Thanks for the help and links.